# How to know Azure Auto Resolve Intigration Runtime IP Address

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to identify How to know Azure Auto Resolve Intigration Runtime IP Address

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/azure-data-factory-now-supports-static-ip-address-ranges/ba-p/1117508.  Datafactory IPs are the same as the Azure Integration runtime IPs but depends on the region where the ADF is created.

Comment: Please explain more why you need that. I have experience with kind of data transfers and it should need be necessary to know that

Answer (score 0):

**The IP addresses that Azure Integration Runtime uses depends on the region where your Azure integration runtime is located.** All Azure integration runtimes that are in the same region use the same IP address ranges. Ref – [Azure Integration Runtime IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses)

Discover service tags by using downloadable JSON file given below.
You can download JSON file that contain the current list of service tags together with IP address range details. These lists are updated and published weekly. Locations for each cloud are:

•   [Azure Public](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519)

You can find `ResourceName` and `Region` as per your requirement from given file.

For more information refer to this [article](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2020/11/process-analysis-service-with-firewall.html)